# tymon/jwt-auth Laravel: Token Signature could not be verified

Tags: laravel, jwt, hashalgorithm

I am getting an access_token from third party successful login.Now i want to decode this token using tymon/jwt-auth and get the payload from that token. When i try to decode same token using [JWT IO debugger](https://jwt.io/#debugger), it successfully decodes the token and payload is as expected. But in laravel when i try to convert that using following code

```
$payload = JWTAuth::decode(new Tymon\JWTAuth\Token($token))
```

I am getting error something like this:

```
Token Signature could not be verified
```

Can anyone please help me with these? Thanks!

Comment: have you registered these `'jwt.auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken', 'jwt.refresh' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken',` in your middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Comment: Also, you need to generate key using: `php artisan jwt:secret`

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.4 - Token Signature could not be verified

Try this: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1124

Comment: This was not working :(. I then used firebase/php-jwt to decode the token